# Jest using toHaveBeenNthCalledWith — why does it give me misleading information

Tags: jestjs

I have an app that is being tested with Jest. The Jest spec runs some code and then asserts that the `fetch` method (which is globally mocked), was received with specific information.

I am using the syntax  `expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(n, ...expected)` but what is frustrating me is that Jest appears to be giving me false and misleading feedback information.

Take a look at the spec:

```
    describe("#leaveCall", () => {
      afterEach(() => {
        delete(global.mock); delete(document.body); delete(global.VDQClient);
      })
      beforeEach( () => {
        mockSetup();
        global.setupMockHtmlFull();
        window.VDQ_GLOBAL = VDQ_GLOBAL();
        window.localStorage.setItem(VDQ_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, "abcdefghijklm")

        global.fetch = jest.fn(() => {
          return Promise.resolve( {json: jest.fn(() => {
              return {id: 111}
            })})
        })
        const VDQClient = new ClientCall(global.mock.navigator);
        VDQClient.start(global.mock.createConsumer);
        VDQClient.makeNewCall();
        VDQClient.callId = "0001";
        VDQClient.leaveCall();
        window.VDQClient = VDQClient;
      })


      test.only("should include the JWT token when sending leave message", () => {

        expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1,
          `//127.0.0.1:3000/calls/0001`, {
          "body": "{}",
          "headers": {"content-type": "application/json", Authorization: "abcdefghijklm" },
          "method": "DELETE"})
      })
    })
```

Now take a look at the Jest output:

```
   expect(jest.fn()).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(n, ...expected)

    n: 1
    Expected: "//127.0.0.1:3000/calls/0001", {"body": "{}", "headers": {"Authorization": "abcdefghijklm", "content-type": "application/json"}, "method": "DELETE"}
    Received
    ->     1
              "//127.0.0.1:3000/calls/0001",
              Object {
                "body": "{}",
                "headers": Object {
            -     "Authorization": "abcdefghijklm",
                  "content-type": "application/json",
                },
                "method": "DELETE",
              },
           2: "//127.0.0.1:3000/calls", {"body": "{\"call\":{\"originatingUrl\":\"http://localhost/\"}}", "headers": {"content-type": "application/json"}, "method": "POST"}

    Number of calls: 3

      156 |       test.only("should include the JWT token when sending leave message", () => {
      157 |
    > 158 |         expect(global.fetch).toHaveBeenNthCalledWith(1,
          |                              ^
      159 |           `//127.0.0.1:3000/calls/0001`, {
      160 |           "body": "{}",
      161 |           "headers": {"content-type": "application/json", Authorization: "abcdefghijklm" },

      at Object.toHaveBeenNthCalledWith (spec/javascript/app/ClientCall.spec.js:158:30)
```

Notice carefully how it says "Received" and then it gives two things it receives: One, the DELETE patch I am trying to test, and two, another unrelated call to `fetch`

(Then it says that there are three calls to fetch, after it just display what looks like 2 calls to fetch)

What does it mean when it shows  `-     "Authorization": "abcdefghijklm",` in green?

To me, that indicates the *received data* on the Nth (1st) fetch call.

but it's not the received data, it is the data that I am expecting in my test.

if I change `abcdefghijklm` to `xyz`, then the output changes to `xyz`.

This makes no sense to me. Why is the expected output showing up under the section marked "Received" when it is clearly not the received output?

What am I missing here.

Comment: Are you clearing your mocks?

Comment: `-     "Authorization": "abcdefghijklm",` tells you that was _not_ found in the value for the 1st call, although you said it was expected. `+     "Authorization": "abcdefghijklm",` would tell you it was received but not expected.

Answer (score 0):

How about refactoring it by:

- Declaring the `fetch` mock once
- Clearing the mock before each test case (instead of deleting a global variable)
- Clearing the mock right before the action
- Moving the action inside the test case

```
global.fetch = jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
  json: () => Promise.resolve({ id: 111 }),
}));

describe("leaving a call", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    fetch.mockClear();
    delete(global.VDQClient);
    delete(document.body);
    mockSetup();
    global.setupMockHtmlFull();
  });

  it('authorized call drop', () => {
    window.VDQ_GLOBAL = VDQ_GLOBAL();
    window.localStorage.setItem(VDQ_LOCAL_STORAGE_KEY, "abcdefghijklm")
    const VDQClient = new ClientCall(global.mock.navigator);
    VDQClient.start(global.mock.createConsumer);
    VDQClient.makeNewCall();
    VDQClient.callId = "0001";
    fetch.mockClear(); // Notice this

    VDQClient.leaveCall();
    window.VDQClient = VDQClient;
    
    expect(fetch).toHaveBeenCalledWith(
      ...
```